# Search results - Order by Date

Tags: search, orderby

We need to order our search results by relevance then post date, however I can't find any reference to order in the ellislab documentation:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/search/index.html

Is this even possible with the search module? If not can anyone recommend a third party addon that would allow us to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehhh I struggled with this one an a previous project. If I remember correctly, there were a few options to do what you're looking for. First of all, these solutions came through Solspace Super Search.

First example is a little weird, but it's because I needed to create functionality that allowed people to search by dates in a various forms (like search for "September 1st" with no year, or "4/15/1880"). In your example, you could basically do this:

```
{exp:super_search:results
    paginate="bottom"
    {!-- other parameters --} 
    limit="10"
    orderby="event_year|event_month|event_day"
    sort="asc|asc|asc"
    relevance="title=5+body=5"}
```

https://solspace.com/docs/super_search/results/#orderby
https://solspace.com/docs/super_search/results/#relevance

According to the docs, it sorts by `relevance` first, and then when you have results with the same relevance, it orders by the `orderby` parameter.

I'm pretty sure you can just leave the `orderby` parameter blank, and it defaults to sorting by `entry_date`. So, set your relevance, and it'll order by `entry_date` after that.

If you're worried, force set like this (assuming ascending date order for equally relevant results):

```
    orderby="entry_date"
    sort="asc"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, guess i'll be downloading super search!